# Not able to understand how a function is returning a specific value when there is no return statement but there is an int return type in C language

Tags: c, recursion, static, return-value

This recursive function 'int f(int n)' should not return anything except when 'n == 1'. If we put
**n = 2,3** then **y = 2**. When **n = 4,5** then **y = 3**, when **n = 6,7,8** then **y = 4 **and so on. Here, *variable x is static.* Below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int f(int n){
        static int x=1; 
        int i;
        if(n==1){
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            for(i = 1; i<=2; i++){
                x = x + f(n-1);
                printf("%d\n",x);
            }
        }
}
int main() {
    int n = 3;
    int y =f(n);
    printf("y %d",y);
    }
```

Kindly help me understand how the value of y is assigned or how f() is returning such values.
Thank you.

I was expecting 2,3,4,5,6,7. I am able to get those values implementing some other stuff but that
is not what I want to understand. I want to understand the f() is 2, when n is 2,3. How f() is returning a value without the return statement?

Comment: If you call a function  that's supposed to return a value, but it doesn't, and you still use the "value" it returns then you have *undefined behavior*. If you declare that a function returns a value, the you *must* explicitly `return` a value.

Comment: It might seem like it's working, but that's purely accidental.

Comment: "I was expecting 2,3,4,5,6,7" And since you don't return anything in the else, it is anyone's guess what the code is supposed to print. If you return `x` then it will be 2,3,6,7,8,16... perhaps not what you intended?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. So, this is undefined behaviour! Got it!! Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

The function `f` doesn't return a value on all code paths.  This means undefined behavior.  It may return anything, or `y` may remain uninitialized.

Comment: ...or catch on fire, or anything else